# How can I use python pdb when running a package directly?

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, package, pdb

I have a nested python package structure that I can install and run different parts of.  For example, to start the Tornado/Flask web server, I execute the following:

```
python3 -m mytool.web -c myconfig.yaml
```

Where the web package contains both an `__init__.py` and a `__main__.py`.  I use this structure in several other components, so once the package is installed it's easy to run, which I do in containers.

My issue is when I'm trying to debug with pdb.  Since pdb is started a similar way I start my package components, i.e. `python3 -m pdb /path/to/debuging/file.py`, I don't know how I can use the pdb tool to debug something else that is ran directly as a package.
`python3 -m pdb mytool.web -c myconfig.yaml` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: haven't found the solution, but here is what i do: create an startup file,import the package and pdb ,adding the flowing code:
`if __name__ == '__main__' pdb.run(module_name.main())

Answer (score 2):

`ipython --pdb -m mytool.web -- -c myconfig.yaml`

This form also works for regular script invocation without the -m
(you need the `--` in both forms to make ipython stop consuming args
and pass them to your module/script)

---

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pdb -m mypackage <myoptions>
```

In your case :

```
python -m pdb -m mytool.web -c myconfig.yaml
```

Though iPython is a great tool, calling the original Python interpreter instead of iPython preserves the original command line since it requires the `python -m pdb -m`  prefix.